# crashes without error referring to a line in my code

Tags: android

Hello guys I'm developing an application that plots a signal on the screen in real-time. This app acquire data from a PCB via bluetooth and just plot the values in a plot. I have a problem right now. I have 3 activity (main, monitoring, btavailable) one thread (listener). from main i press a connect button and i go in btavailable waiting for a result from this activity. Once i have the result i start the monitoring activity which throws the thread for listening from the bluetooth. If I go back the main activity is called so I'm able to press the connect button again. When I press the connect button again my purpose is to call directly the monitoring activity but... the app restart from the beginning without opening the monitoring activity. It seems that the app do it several time and also when i try to connect using the btavailable monitoring the app restarts. I'm using graphview and the only error that i can see seems to come from there. Android does not give me an error in none of my line code and this is the worst condition, as you surely know.

This is my error:

```
04-30 12:50:37.860 12375-12375/com.example.utente.lets_appv0 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.utente.lets_appv0, PID: 12375
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Capacity: -8
                                                                               at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:140)
                                                                               at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:174)
                                                                               at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:119)
                                                                               at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:97)
                                                                               at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:81)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.adjustVertical(GridLabelRenderer.java:768)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.adjustSteps(GridLabelRenderer.java:932)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.draw(GridLabelRenderer.java:1067)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.drawGraphElements(GraphView.java:299)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.draw(GridLabelRenderer.java:1062)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.drawGraphElements(GraphView.java:299)
                                                                               at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.onDraw(GraphView.java:323)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
                                                                               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
                                                                               at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
                                                                               at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2383)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2255)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1885)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5672)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:772)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:585)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:758)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loo
```

and another two errors are:

```
04-30 12:50:38.480 2375-2375/? E/SearchServiceStarter: Task 174 failed or timed out. Client 10446885107087741 disconnecting from SearchService!
                                                   java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.da(SourceFile:80)
                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:62)
                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cf.o(SourceFile:2)
                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ax.m(SourceFile:50)
                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.az.run(SourceFile:5)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bf.run(SourceFile:2)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and:

```
04-30 12:50:38.660 801-9057/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (FetchAclSet) got error statusCode=-1.
                                    com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online?
                                        at djc.a(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320):62)
                                        at dej.run(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320):2)
                                        at deh.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320):3)
                                        at koh.run(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320):6)
                                        at kot.run(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320):26)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                        at kus.run(com.google.android.gms@12221034@12.2.21 (034-188803320))
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I don't know if the last two errors are correlated with the first one, but you know, StackOverflow is mad for asking.

Thank you all anyway :)

Comment: Are you assigning something -8 value?

Comment: You are initializing your HashMap with -8 which is not permissible. Check your code and if you cannot find issue, update your code in your question

Comment: show your code. `GridLabelRenderer.java:768` this line

Comment: My entire code is too long to post it here. It might have more sense to put it on github and then link here the repository. Anyway my errors are not coming from my code but from a library that I'm using. As you can see errors come from GraphView, which is a library that you can find online....